# What effect does calibrating the Kinect have?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How much of a difference does in make to calibrate the Kinect using the procedure described in http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect/Tutorials/Calibrating%20the%20Kinect ? How much of an improvement is there with the new parameters versus just using the default parameters?

Are there any other kinect calibration routines I should know about?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9147/what-effect-does-calibrating-the-kinect-have?/) by [Deon Joubert](https://answers.ros.org/users/54/deon-joubert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As has been mentioned, the OpenNI drivers give you access to the factory calibration, which means you don't need to calibrate manually.

However, if you want to anyway (for example, to use libfreenect on systems that don't have ROS), it makes a huge difference in the alignment of the points and RGB values.

An easy way to demonstrate this is to fire up rviz, and visualize the PointCloud2 that's published by the kinect_camera driver; if you haven't calibrated, you'll notice a serious mismatch between the points and colors. If you then switch to the openni_camera driver, you'll notice how much better things are. Calibrating the sensor manually (kinect_calibration) will get alignment performance on par with openni_camera.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5